# How can you set a default calendar to use for new events on a LG Android 2.2.1 phone?

Tags: calendar

My wife bought a LG-P350 phone running Android 2.2.2.

Is it possible to set the default calender to use when entering new appointments using the agenda application ?

She added the google account of my son to her accounts, and now , every time a new appointment is created, the last agenda of my son's account is selected.

I have found no obvious way to change this default.

I don't know if this is the stock application of Android.

Comment: Same with my LG-P920 with Android 2.2.2, is this an LG specific thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no one is answering this question, I presume it is not possible.

So I looked for another solution and found the [Business Calender Free edition](https://market.android.com/details?id=netgenius.bizcal&feature=search_result). This program not only displays a very nice monthly calender, but , most important, let you choose which colour you want to use for each agenda you want to display.

Very impressive indeed.

Just thought I'd let you know ...

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a way to prevent accidentally adding personal events to my shared work calendar. Ironic that the app that enables me to do that is called "Business Calendar" :).